# Simple terminal graphics package?

Tags: bash, graphics

I would like to know if there are any kinds of packages dedicated to ASCII graphics, like drawing lines and plotting points using characters in terminal. I already made a script for plotting points with a "#" character, but it kinda sucks to use. Is there anything out there that describes what I'm looking for?

Comment: Sounds to me like `nucrses`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti What is `nucrses`?

Answer (score 3):

`gnuplot` is the way to go for things like this.

```
gnuplot> set terminal dumb
Terminal type set to 'dumb'
Options are 'feed 79 24'
gnuplot> plot sin(x)

   1 ++----------------**---------------+----**-----------+--------**-----++
     +                *+ *              +   *  *          +  sin(x) ****** +
 0.8 ++              *    *                *    *                *    *   ++
     |               *    *                *    *                *    *    |
 0.6 ++              *     *              *      *              *      *  ++
     *              *       *             *       *             *      *   |
 0.4 +*             *       *             *       *             *      *  ++
     |*            *        *            *        *            *        *  |
 0.2 +*            *        *            *        *            *        * ++
     | *          *          *          *          *          *          * |
   0 ++*          *          *          *          *          *          *++
     |  *         *           *         *           *         *           *|
-0.2 ++ *         *           *         *           *         *           *+
     |   *       *            *        *            *        *            *|
-0.4 ++  *       *            *        *            *        *            *+
     |   *      *              *      *              *      *              *
-0.6 ++  *      *              *      *              *      *             ++
     |    *     *               *     *               *    *               |
-0.8 ++    *   *                 *   *                *    *              ++
     +     *  *        +         *  *   +              *  *                +
  -1 ++-----**---------+----------**----+---------------**+---------------++
    -10               -5                0                 5                10
```

Comment: Not specifically what I was looking for, but I'll definitly get this! What i'm looking for is something that puts characters directly to the screen with console columns and rows. Like `point 1 1`, and it puts a character in prompt row one, column one.

Comment: It can plot points from a data file as well. I just didn't have a file of data points handy to plot.